# Start Terminal and Run python script on boot

Tags: boot, lxterminal, desktop

I have been struggling with this all day. My set up is a RPi 3 B, running Raspbian.

I need to simply fulfil the following:

1. Once booted automatically open Terminal
2. cd to/my/directory
3. run_my_script.py
4. After 10 minutes, close terminal (or reboot) and repeat

I have limited knowledge of shell and desktop scripts.

Comment: You want to reboot RPi every 10 minutes after running the script? why? You probably don't need to launch terminal to run a python script.

Answer (score 1):

wrote a bash script with folling content:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 /path_to_your_script/python_script.py


sudo shutdown -r +10
# or with sleep
sleep(600)
sudo reboot now
```

r: reboot

+10: 10 minutes

go to:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and fill in the path to bash script, before the exit 0 statement:

```
bash /path_to_bash/bash_script.sh &
```

of course you could do it with python so you would not need a separate bash script

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will attempt to implement this now. 

One query I have is that the script seems to not have a command to open the terminal window, is this not possible in a bash script?

Comment: to open a terminal, use command "lxterminal -e "command_to_execute" http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html

Comment: Here is my script.

     #!/bin/bash

     lxterminal -e "cd /home/pi/iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app/ && 
     python wbuoy4.py"


     sudo shutdown -r +10