# How to run a terminal command on startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-buster, alexa

I'm new how can I run the following terminal command on startup:

```
"cd /home/pi/sdk-folder/sdk-build \ PA_ALSA_PLUGHW=1 ./SampleApp/src/SampleApp ./Integration/AlexaClientSDKConfig.json ../third-party/alexa-rpi/models"
```

I have tried methods with rc.local and the autostart one but I don't think I am getting it right. ANy ideas?

Comment: use systemd unit

Comment: Is that all one, single command? If so, please put it in a "code-fence" (```) to make it clear. I've edited your question to add the code fences - please review & place the code fences where they should be, add any required line breaks, etc.

Comment: Similar to your question is raised in the link below
[Start Terminal and Run python script on boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77490/start-terminal-and-run-python-script-on-boot)

Comment: Similar to your question is raised in the link below https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77490/start-terminal-and-run-python-script-on-boot

Comment: And to @Ali.kavari76 the question is for a python script and I want to run a terminal command. Is it the same? I'm new to Raspberry Pi's so I don't know the difference

Comment: Have also a look at this tag [(systemd-startup)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd-startup)